Using Intent to access files(e.g. images, mp3...) in Android Studio
I am new and learning Android Studio. Currently, I want to use intent to get access to images and audio files in my android devices.
Here is my original code (actually copying from old books)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Button mBtnBrowseWWW, mBtnPlayMP3, mBtnViewImg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mBtnPlayMP3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnPlayMP3);
        mBtnViewImg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnViewImg);

        mBtnPlayMP3.setOnClickListener(btnPlayMP3OnClick);
        mBtnViewImg.setOnClickListener(btnViewImgOnClick);
    }

    private View.OnClickListener btnPlayMP3OnClick = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            String sMp3File = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
                    File.separator + "song.mp3";
            File file = new File(sMp3File);
            boolean b = file.exists();
            it.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "audio/*");
            startActivity(it);
        }
    };

    private View.OnClickListener btnViewImgOnClick = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            String sImgFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
                    File.separator + "image.png";
            File file = new File(sImgFile);
            it.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "image/*");
            startActivity(it);
        }
    };
}

And it shows the following error message:
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///storage/emulated/0/image.png exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()

I search the problem in the interent and found out that I shall use FileProvider. I amend my AndroidManifest.xml by adding the following lines:
<provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>

And create a provider_paths.xml file;
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <external-path name="image" path="."/>
    <external-path name="song" path="."/>
</paths>

But I don't know how to change my MainActivity script. Can anyone give me some advices on the MainAcitivity part and explain the script in details? Thanks a lot.
''' EDIT '''
Thank you so much to mayankk28. By combining his answer with another post enter link description here, I change my btnViewImgOnClick to the form below:
Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String sImgFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
                File.separator + "image.png";
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, sImgFile, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        File file = new File(sImgFile);
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(getApplicationContext()),
                BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
        it.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
        it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(it);

I put my image.png in the directory below:
storage/emulated/0/image.png
But the app replies that "media not found" when I click the third button. Where shall I put my image.png?

getExternalStorageDirectory returns a top-level directory. You are not supposed to use it directly. I recommend looking at the docs: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared

Please try modifying your btnViewImgOnClick onClickListener as below :
private View.OnClickListener btnViewImgOnClick = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            String sImgFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
                    File.separator + "image.png";
            File file = new File(sImgFile);
            Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(v.getContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".fileprovider", file);

            it.setDataAndType(uri, "image/*");
            it.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(it);
        }
    };

The receiving app should have grantUriPermissions to access the file.

Thank you very much to your answer. I combine your answer with another's post and now the program does not crash. But I would like to ask where I shall put my image.png? I put it in the directory (in the Edit part above) but the app replies that "no media found".

You need to place image.png in the directory specified in your FileProvider configuration.
